# Where in the Torah is the "ascending order of importance" derived?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, agriculture, shavuos, ki-tavo, bikkurim-first-fruits

Where in the Torah is the "ascending order of importance" derived, as used by the Temple Institute in describing the basket of firstfruits?

They wrote,

[> "The fruits were arranged in ascending order of importance: the bottom

> basket contained barley. This was followed by wheat, olives, dates,
> pomegranates,and figs. A dove was set on the top."][1](https://templeinstitute.org/shavuot-2/)

Looking at the [illustration](https://templeinstitute.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/favorite-fruits.jpg) of such "ascending order of importance" by the Temple Institute, it seems there is a dove in both the bottom level and on the top level? How does this reflect the phrase "ascending order of importance"?

Because this question is a follow-up of [Who used the "Special seven tiered baskets" that "were employed to display the firstfruits"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/122301/who-used-the-special-seven-tiered-baskets-that-were-employed-to-display-the-f)

I understand that the basket of firstfruits is based on Bikkurim Chapter 3:
https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1002529/jewish/Bikkurim-Chapter-3.htm

There, it mentions that grapes (one of the seven fruits of [Devarim 8:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9972/showrashi/true)) are used to "surround the figs". This begs the question, where in the "ascending order of importance" should the grapes be?

Comment: I think some [artistic license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license) was taken in that illustration. For instance, in [Eliyahu Touger's translation of Bikkurim 3:9](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1002529/jewish/Bikkurim-Chapter-3.htm#v9), it says: "_When they would bring the first fruits, they would also bring turtle doves and doves **in their hands**. Similarly, they would hang turtle doves and doves **from the sides of the baskets** in order to adorn the first fruits_". (Emphasis mine) ...

Comment: ... In [footnote #24](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1002529/jewish/Bikkurim-Chapter-3.htm#footnote24a1002529) there, it say: "_They were not placed on the baskets themselves, lest they soil the fruit [the Rambam's Commentary to the Mishnah (Bikkurim 3:5)]_". This is at variance with the illustration, which has doves both in, and on top of, the basket.

Comment: @TamirEvan your comments here, which seems logical, might serve as an answer that I would accept. In your quote of Bikkurim 3:9, when they "hang turtle doves and doves from the sides of the baskets", are these dead or living? What is the difference between turtle doves and doves?

Comment: I was just presenting my personal opinion of the illustration. It could be there are positions different from those in the Mishneh Torah, and the Temple Institute reconciled them in their own way. (I vaguely remember them doing something like that with the design of their Menorah.) In general, I'm unsure how correct or authoritative the Temple Institute's depictions are. I think they are doing an important job, of bringing the Temple, and its service, into peoples hearts and minds. I just wish a more authoritative/reliable body was behind the endeavor.

Comment: Regarding the "turtle doves and doves" dead or alive: Later in Bikkurim 3:9, it says: "_Those that were with the baskets would be offered as burnt offerings and those they would bring by hand would be given to the priests [as presents]_". From that, my understanding is that they were alive (as the priest would be the one killing them, as part of making the burnt offering). If your asking about the "_lest they soil the fruit_" part in the footnote, I think that means by defecating on, or eating from, the fruit.

Comment: This is mentioned in the Tosefta ([Bikkurim 2:8](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/f/f1b.htm)) and Y'rushalmi ([Bikkurim 3:5](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1b03.htm)), and codified by the Rambam ([Hil. Bikkurim 3:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1002529/jewish/Bikkurim-Chapter-3.htm)). The wording in the Tosefta and the Y'rushalmi suggests that bringing the first fruits mixed together is not proper but also not disqualifying. The Rambam's interpretation is that although separation into different vessels is merely ideal, stacking the fruits distinctly is required (at least ab initio).